# How to implement record video in the tango

Tags: android, tango

I develop tango AR app using Unity, I want to record the AR video, but I can't find a API to record video in the tango Android device, so I have to use Android API. in the Unity project, I import tango's unity SDK package, so, at Plugins/Android directory, there are a AndroidManifest.xml file and google_unity_wrapper.aar, If I want to use Android API, how to integrate my code into google_unity_wrapper.aar?